# Laravel requesting route and checking if user is logged in via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm using Laravel version 7.11.0 and this is the scenario

1. User logs into his account
2. User doesn't do anything on the webpage for a while so his session expires
3. The user hits a button on my webpage that sends a Post request via Ajax to a route that can
   only be used by authenticated users
4. Laravel correctly blocks that request because the user is not logged in

If that happens I would like to redirect that user to the login page. I know Laravel can do that but it isn't working when I'm using Ajax. So how can this be done when using Ajax ? Thanks in advance.

The Route definition:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','throttle:20,1']], function() {

Route::post('/searchProduct','ProductController@searchProduct')->name('searchProduct');

});
```

The Ajax Request

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/searchProduct',
            data: {
                search_term: $(".search_term").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.msg);

            },

                error: function (data) {

                console.log(errors.message);

            }
        });
```

Comment: What is returned by AJAX in this case? Does it return error?

Comment: Returns an object , one of the entries in the object --> exception: "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user is logged out you will retrieve an error.
Than if you can make another ajax call that will check if user is logged in:

```
// Laravel
return auth()->check()
```

If this request receives `false` then you can redirect him to login page